# Why C# program started show "Unknown publisher" when executed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am developing C# application in Visual Studio 2015. Old versions of my app were able to run on someone else's computer without showing any message. But when I run newer version of my app on someone else's computer, I get warning "Unknown publisher".
I am not aware of changing something important between old and new version. I dont want to pay for certificate and sign my app.
Do you have any idea why someone else's computer started to show this message (what could changed)?
Thank you very much for any idea.

Comment: Are you using _ClickOnce_ deployment?

Comment: "I dont want to pay for certificate and sign my app." - then you are an unknown publisher...

Comment: It looks more like the security checks on the other computer has been updated. I'm not sure it's linked to your app (which was already from "unknown publisher" anyway). Anyway, even if the warning can be deactivated on the other computer, I'm not sure it's a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

This is "Open File - Security Warning". I am also a C# developer, but I have not faced this type of issue when running my developed app in my PC, but it is true that when I run those apps on another PC I get a popup that states "Open File - Security Warning".

Please follow the steps If you does not want to get Security Warning.

1. Run **GPEDIT.MSC**.
2. **Local Computer Policy** / **User Configuration** / **Administrative Templates** / **Windows Components** / **Attachment Manager**
3. On the right pane, double click Inclusion list for low file types.
4. Click Enable.
5. Include the file types such as .exe;.bat;.reg;.vbs in the Options box.
6. Click OK.

Hope this helps.